# Is there any way to make a cross domain iframe change parent frame's location when a link is clicked inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a website on domain a.com, which contains an iframe on domain b.com . b.com can contain relative or absolute links. **I do not have access to b.com's code**

I would like that clicked **links** in the iframe would **redirect the parent frame** (the browser window) **and not the iframe** to the link's location.

I have tried listening to location changes on the iframe, but I can't access location object because of cross domain policy. The iframe SRC doesn't change when the location changes. Any solution ?

Comment: I see you've edited it to clarify you don't have access to the inner domain since I posted my answer - I'm not sure you will have a solution here in that case.

Comment: Unless you have access to b.com's code, this simply isn't possible.

Comment: Why are you including client websites inside your site in an iframe? why can't it instead be done through, say, ajax, through cooperation with your client to provide what you need through ajax?

Comment: We provide solutions for customers who do not know programming. We take existing websites and wrap them in our product which "enhances them". In some cases, very rare though, we cannot proxy their websites; that is why I needed cross-platform iframe access.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `target` attribute on your link:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_top">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I don't have access to the code of b.com.

Comment: yeah I saw your edit :)  Not sure you will be able to solve this without changes on the inner domain.  You won't be able to do anything through JavaScript due to the cross domain issues.

Comment: I guessed so... iframes point to our client's websites. I guess the simplest method is to ask them to inject <base target="_parent" /> in their <head>. was just wondering if there was anything else possible